# Invoke function only on the selected ng-repeat element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

Currently I am trying to fetch some data using JSON and have structured it over my website using ng-repeat.

The problem is that on ng-click, on any newly created element the function invokes on each element as well. I have also tried using the **this** operator but it doesnt seem to work on angularjs.

I have created a dummy problem similar to mine.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="aplhabet in word">
            <button style="width:50px; margin: 5px"  ng-click="addDiv()">
                <b>{{aplhabet}}</b>
            </button>
            <section ng-show="newdiv">functionInvoked</section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        function MyCtrl($scope){
            $scope.word = 'STRINGDEMO';    
            $scope.addDiv = function () {
                $scope.newdiv = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you might notice whenever you click on any button the function runs for each element. I need help to understand how to pass any identifier in this function so that the function is invoked only on the element clicked.

Comment: Pass `alphabet` as a parameter to your `addDiv` function. And in the function you can evaluate based on the value whether to perform certain action or not.

Comment: Please add a plunkr or jsfiddle of your working code!

Comment: Pass aplhabet as a parameter to addDiv with ng-click="addDiv(aplhabet")

Answer (score 1):

you need an object array to achieve this. simply use a for loop to convert this to an array of object.

```
for(key in $scope.word){
  $scope.wordArr.push({
      letter : $scope.word[key],
      newDiv : false
  })
}
```

use the new array as `ng-repeat`. to print letter use `<b>{{aplhabet.letter}}</b>`

```
<div ng-repeat="aplhabet in wordArr">
  <button style="width:50px; margin: 5px"  ng-click="addDiv(aplhabet)">
    <b>{{aplhabet.letter}}</b>
  </button>
  <section ng-show="aplhabet.newdiv">functionInvoked
  </section>
</div>
```

in the `ng-click` pass the whole object as a parameter and change the `newDiv` to true

Demo

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope){
$scope.word = 'STRINGDEMO';  
$scope.wordArr = [];

for(key in $scope.word){
  $scope.wordArr.push({
      letter : $scope.word[key],
      newDiv : false
  })
}
$scope.addDiv = function (aplhabet) {
   aplhabet.newdiv = true;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="aplhabet in wordArr">
<button style="width:50px; margin: 5px"  ng-click="addDiv(aplhabet)">
<b>{{aplhabet.letter}}</b>
</button>
<section ng-show="aplhabet.newdiv">functionInvoked
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$index`

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="aplhabet in word track by $index">
            <button style="width:50px; margin: 5px"  ng-click="addDiv($index)">
                <b>{{aplhabet}}</b>
            </button>
            <section ng-show="newdiv">functionInvoked</section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        function MyCtrl($scope){
            $scope.word = 'STRINGDEMO';    
            $scope.addDiv = function (index) {
                //do your stuff here
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```